# Scapy: How to send packet to one interface and receive from another?

Tags: python, scapy

Situation: I have raspberry where I want to launch my Scapy's script. I want to send a packet from ETH0 to my device, which is connected to raspberry, and receive a message from ETH1 (make a loop: raspberry's ETH0 -> device's ETH0 -> device's ETH1 -> raspberry -> ETH1). How can I customize my delivery?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `iface=` to specify the interfaces.
For instance:

```
pkt = Ether()/IP()/UDP()
sendp(pkt, iface="eth0")
sniff(iface="eth1", count=5)
```

Assuming you want to listen to the actual answer (match the response), you could use something like

```
pkt = Ether()/IP()/UDP()
s = lambda: sendp(pkt, iface="eth0")
sniff(iface="eth1", started_callback=s, count=1, filter=lambda p: p.answers(pkt), timeout=2)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import socket
host = '192.168.1.9'
port = 5000

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.sendto('hello', (host, port))
print("Message sent")

print("Sending to port {0}".format(port))
s.sendto('hi', (host, port))
print("Message received")
s.close()
```

Comment: You just send 2 messages to the same host/port